# Why do my CSS styles disappear when I refresh the page in Next.js?

Tags: css, next.js, jsx, refresh

I created a CSS folder in my app folder and wrote my CSS files there. And then imported them in components to use. They are applied in first load. But when I refresh the page, they all disappear.

[image: my folder structure]

I tried going back and saving those files again and it worked but disappearing happens every time I refresh again.

Comment: I think the problem is how next.js is configured to send a template with hydration after and the hydration is probably not getting the CSS though, this is just in theory though i have not used next.js enough to know this for sure. If this is the case maybe look for something how to render this even when using hydration

Comment: Do you load the css in the components where you need it or globally in the index.js?

Comment: I import the CSS files in the components where they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In next js can't load css inside each single page components. Only can load inside
**pages/_app.js**

```
import '../styles.css'

// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

If need to call inside single components they should be CSS modules.

for ex: **components/layout.js**

```
import styles from './layout.module.css';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <div className={styles.container}>{children}</div>;
}
```

In **components/layout.module.css**

```
.container {
  max-width: 36rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin: 3rem auto 6rem;
}
```

More can find [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tired this , but the same issue still remains. Looks like something else causes it. If you will have any other ideas , please let me know

Comment: I solved the issue. Looks like it was about the Next.js layout. I was sending my changing component wrongly to the layout as children. I fixed it and CSS styles don't disappear anymore.